# Passing JSON as an html attribute

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am experiencing an issue where I am in need of passing a JSON as an HTML attribute. I have the JSON string:

> {"filename":"myFile.js","content":"var k = 'My Value'"}

Which I am passing to a html attribute:

```
<ide file-json='{"filename":"myFile.js","content":"var k = 'My Value'"}'></ide>
```

The issue occurs where `var k = 'My Value'` as the `'` mark is unescaped and causing the html parser to think the value of attribute `file-json` is `{"filename":"myFile.js","content":"var k =` rather than the full string. The `file-json` attribute is going to be read via javascript for additional processing.

The values for both the json keys of `filename` and `content` are user generated, and can have almost any value. Is there a way escape the entire `file-json` attribute?

Things that I have already tried, and the reason for their failure are below: (The actual json input can be extremely large.)

- Use a giant regular expression to escape any offending instances in the json file. This for two primary reasons, the first being that it was slow, but more importantly it is a "dumb" solution and often makes mistakes causing additional errors, and data corruption.
- Convert the entire json structure into base64/hex; pass this encoded structure to `file-json`; and then in the javascript when it is read, convert it from base64 back into a json string; and finally continue processing. This so far is the best solution that I have come up with as it is the only one that cannot cause data corruption. However it is both slow and consists of a large number of moving parts leading to issues in maintainability and expandability.

Comment: Why not just format it properly before you put it there? Just do `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data))` and you'll get a normalised representation

Comment: *"Which I am passing to a html attribute"*....Is this being populated in some server side code? If so should be easy to escape there

Answer (score 3):

Your json looks like valid json, so a simple JSON.stringify should do the job

```
var json = {"filename":"myFile.js","content":"var k = 'My Value'"}
var stringified = JSON.stringify(json);
// or whatever element identifier you have
document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('file-json', stringified)
```

if not and its really a string, simply add `JSON.parse()`

```
var stringified = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json));
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/czuwxqsk/)